# Order of execution in junit

Tags: java, selenium, junit, automation

My code

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;

@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
public class Order {

    @Test
    @Order(4)
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("This is test 1");
    }

    @Test
    @Order(3)
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("This is test 2");
    }

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    public void test3() {
        System.out.println("This is test 3");
    }

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void test4() {
        System.out.println("This is test 4");
    }
}
```

The output of the code

```
This is test 1
This is test 2
This is test 3
This is test 4
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with the code?
I need to execute it in the order that I provided.

Comment: Normally unit test order of execution is not guaranteed, and your test should never depend on the order of the execution of test cases because each case should be independent.

Comment: Because your class is called `Order` I had to use fully-qualified class names for `@Order` (`@@org.junit.jupiter.api.Order`). When I ran the test the methods were executed in the expected order: 4, 3, ,2 ,1.

Answer (score 1):

Change the first import - `import org.junit.Test;` to `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`, that is the issue here.
I've got output as:

```
This is test 4
This is test 3
This is test 2
This is test 1
```